# php pagination hide previous and next button using symfony framework

Tags: php, pagination, symfony1

Hi, I have this pagination using the symfony framework, I'm wondering how to hide the button if the page is already in first page, so no previous button, and if last page no next button.

How will I able to get the currentPage?

Here's my code:

```
<?php if ($pager->haveToPaginate()) :?>
  <div class="pagerWrapper ">
    <nav>
      <ul class="pager"> 
        <?php if($currPage != 1):?>
          <li class="pageNumber"><?php echo link_to('<img alt="Previous Page" src="/images/pager_prev_btn.png" class="page_img" />', url_for('contract/index?page='.$pager->getPreviousPage()), 'class=""' )?></li>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php foreach ($pager->getLinks() as $page) :?>
          <li class="pageNumber"><?php echo link_to($page, url_for('contract/index?page='.$page), ($page == $pager->getPage()) ?'class="selected"' : 'class=""')?></li>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php if($pager->getLastPage() != $currPage): ?>
          <li class="pageNumber"><?php echo link_to('<img alt="Next Page" src="/images/pager_next_btn.png" class="page_img" />', url_for('contract/index?page='.$pager->getNextPage()),'class=""')?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

heres my controller

```
 public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request){
    $currPage = $request->getParameter('page', 1);
    $limit = sfConfig::get('app_contract_list_limit');
    $offset = ($currPage - 1) * $limit;
    $q = ContractTable::getInstance()->getContractList($offset,$limit);
    $this->contractList = $q->execute();

    $this->pager = new sfDoctrinePager('Contract', $limit);
    $this->pager->setQuery($q);
    $this->pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));     

    $this->pager->init();
  }
```

please help I'm confused, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current page with `$pager->getPage()`
According to :
http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#paginating-results

And for first and last page you can use something like that :

```
if (!$pager->isFirstPage())
{
}
foreach ($pager->getLinks() as $page)
{
}
if (!$pager->isLastPage())
{
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks on this its only the $this->currPage that im using ,,ive got it